# Unable to read data from pdf files using java

Tags: java, pdf, automation, pdfbox

I have saved a pdf file. If i open it in chrome iam able to see all the fields. But when i open in pdf editor some fields are missing.I am trying to read the data using pdfbox so some fields are missing. Is there any way i could open this file in browser and read the data.

Comment: What have you tried? What language are you in? You tagged [tag:java] and [tag:python]

Comment: I tried in java but some fields are missing. So i need a solution to open the file in browser and read the data.

Comment: What did you try in Java (maybe you did something wrong)? And which file did you try it with (there are some broken files different libraries make more or less sense of)?

Comment: `I am trying to read the data using pdfbox so some fields are missing` - also missing: your code, the PDFBox version, the names of the missing fields, and the PDF itself.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the missing parts.